# Max key in multi-key hash

Tags: ruby, hashtable

This is my hash :

```
  h_letters = {
    first: {
      value: 2,
      text: "H"
    },
    second: {
      value: 2,
      text: "HH"
    },
    third: {
      value: 4,
      text: "HHH"
    }
  }
```

And I want to get the text of the biggest value of my entire hash.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h_letters.max_by { |h| h.last[:value] }.last[:text] #=> "HHH"
```

Comment: How can I expect the better case if all my value are same.. If all those values are 2, I expect "third" text..

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you're talking about, you should write several specific examples of input data and the results you're expecting.